# PHP radiobutton on click event change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created the following code.
for some reason its skips my if event when the radiobutton changes.
the if statment is whitin a FORM i dont think this matters?

```
<p><?php echo $rijden[$lan][0];?></p><input type="radio" name="JA" id="waarde1" value="waarde1"  onClick="gestuurdjanee();"><b>Ja</b> <input type="radio" name="JA" value="waarde0" id="waarde0" onClick="gestuurdjanee();" ><b>Nee</b></br>
    <?php
        function gestuurdjanee() {
            if(document.getElementById("waarde0").checked == true) {
                          //nee?>
                <p><?php echo $merk[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="merk"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $totaalassen[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="totaalassen"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $gestuurdenassen[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="gestuurdenassen"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $asconfig[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="asconfig2"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $onstype[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="typebesturing"/></p>

         <?php
            }elseif(document.getElementById("waarde1").checked == true) {
                          //ja?>
                <p><?php echo $typeconcurent[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="typetrailer"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $asconfig[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="asconfig"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $merk[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="merk"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $onstype[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="onstype"/></p>
                <p><?php echo $gestuurdas[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="gestuurdas"/></p>
             <?php
        }
        else {
            // niksingevuld
        ?>
        <?php echo"Vink een van de optie's aan"?>
        <?php
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you enclosing JavaScript in `<?php ?>` ? your `if(document.getElementById("waarde0").checked == true)` is JavaScript you have it inside `<?php ?>` that's why it's skipping the statement. Also your coding is all over the place.

Comment: why do you have js code in your php?

Comment: because op doesn't know the difference between serverside and clientside yet I guess. I would hazard a guess at a dutch first year coding education.

Comment: @Max PHP code runs once, on the server. The result is sent to the browser, and only then is any JS code executed. You're expecting them to somehow run in parallel, which is not how it works at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining JS and PHP like that won't work. As been commented, the PHP will only run once on the server. When it's done, it shows the result in the browser. Then the Javascript will run.

Instead create three divisions with different classes.

Then bind an event on changing the input.

Also see the comments in my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.div1, .div2').hide(); // hide div1 and div2 on page load
  
  $('[name=JA]').on('change', function() { // bind an onchange function to the inputs
    if( $('[name=JA]:checked').val() == 'waarde1' ) { // get the value that is checked
      $('.div1').show();        // show div1
      $('.div2, .div3').hide(); // hide other divs
    }
    else {
      $('.div2').show();        // show div2
      $('.div1, .div3').hide(); // hide other divs
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <?php echo $rijden[$lan][0];?>
</p><input type="radio" name="JA" id="waarde1" value="waarde1"><b>Ja</b> 
<input type="radio" name="JA" value="waarde0" id="waarde0"><b>Nee</b></br>


<div class="div1">
DIV1
  <p>
    <?php echo $merk[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="merk" /></p>
  <p>
    <?php echo $totaalassen[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="totaalassen" /></p>
  <p>
    <?php echo $gestuurdenassen[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="gestuurdenassen" /></p>
  <p>
    <?php echo $asconfig[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="asconfig2" /></p>
  <p>
    <?php echo $onstype[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="typebesturing" /></p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
DIV2
    <p>
      <?php echo $typeconcurent[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="typetrailer" /></p>
    <p>
      <?php echo $asconfig[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="asconfig" /></p>
    <p>
      <?php echo $merk[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="merk" /></p>
    <p>
      <?php echo $onstype[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="onstype" /></p>
    <p>
      <?php echo $gestuurdas[$lan][0];?> <input type="text" name="gestuurdas" /></p>
</div>
<div class="div3">Vink een van de optie's aan</div>
```